# Power BI - Merge field names as one

Tags: powerbi

I have the following names on my table 'DependantTypes'
-Self
-Spouse
-Child
 I would like to create a bar graph that would display 'self' as a column, then combine "Spouse" and "Child" as one. This way, I'll be able to achieve the total amount for this two
The amount filed exists in the "TtlAmounts"

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you can create a calculated column that combines non-self types and then use that on your chart instead of `DependantTypes`.

```
SelfOrOther = IF ( [DependantTypes] = "Self", "Self", "Other" )
```

You can, of course, change the name of the column or what you want to return in either case (e.g. `"Spouse/Child"` instead of `"Other"`).